# Extract Data as JSON

Tags: scala, slick, anorm

I'm working on an API and would like it as efficient as possible. I have no obvious need to translate into case classes or any other strucrure besides the JSON I send to the client.  Is there any easy way to extract JSON directly instead of row data -> class -> JSON. I'm open to use anorm, Slick, or anything else, I just need it to be lightweight.

If I were to use Mongo, shouldn't I be able to extract JSON from my store and transform it without having the overhead of deserializing to an object?  Shouldn't I be able to use JSON <-> JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Casbah](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah) as the MongoDB Scala driver.

For example, extracting the JSON stored in mongodb for your *user* with *id==1* from mongodb becomes as easy as:

```
val obj : Option[DBObject] = db.users.findOne(MongoDBObject("user.id" -> 1))
val json : String = obj.map(_.get("user").toString)
                             .getOrElse(throw new Exception("error..."))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just build your API over MongoDB as your datastore (http://www.mongodb.org/). Then you can store, and retrieve your data as JSON docs.

Comment: I have gone down the path of Mongo in the past and analysing the data becomes difficult especially without the power of SQL.

Comment: The query language has expanded alot over the years. I would be interested in knowing the scenarios where you couldn't do what you wanted. MongoDB should really be better at querying JSON documents than SQL which works best with normalized relational data. If there are some gaps, they need to be filled.